# Is it possible for a dragonborn to have 2 different breath weapons

Tags: dnd-5e, dragonborn, breath-weapon

I just found this site while searching for an answer to my question.

While I haven't played D&D yet, I am extremely interested in trying. I know a lot of DMs do things differently and are relatively loose with the rules (within reason I'm sure).

I've been thinking about making a Dragonborn character for whenever I get the opportunity to play, but I wanted to run a question by some DMs and see what they think.

I was thinking about creating a mixed heritage Dragonborn (ex. Red and Blue), knowing that both are different and thus give different breath weapons and resistances to their respective elements. I was hoping that the character could have access to both breath weapons and that they could be used in the same day in game. In order to counter what could potentially be a rule breaking and overpowered character I thought that for

1. If said character were to use it's second breath weapon it would
   have to wait 2 long rests before being able to use the secondary
   breath again. While still allowing for the first or primary breath
   weapon to be used again after a short rest.
2. As for the resistances offered by the heritages I was think it could
   be just a 25% resistance to the respective elements or I could only
   choose 1 element to get the full 50% resistance.

I hope that I'm clear with my idea and question. I'm also curious to know if any of y'all have ever come across someone wanting to do something similar.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Are you asking us to judge your proposed homebrew rule for allowing this, or whether there's any way to have 2 breath weapons by the rules? We're kind of strict on "one, single, clear question per question" due to the whole voting and answering system, so it needs to be clear which problem you need resolved.

Comment: Hello NefariousJester! You can ask two separate questions: if it is possible for a dragonborn to have 2 different breath weapons by RAW (for example) and if your homebrew dragonborn (along with it's traits) is balanced.

Comment: Welcome! Take the [tour] if you haven't already.

Comment: If you find that you can't get this question into a stackable form, per above comments, we have a [curated list of forums](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449/22566) where such a brainstorming/idea generation proposal may fit better.

Comment: I changed the hold reason to “too broad”. (NB to hold voters: if it’s unclear because it has two questions and it’s not clear which the asker might want to narrow it down to, it’s more instructive to use “too broad”. “Unclear” is for when we can’t tell what the question is in the first place or it’s missing vital details.)

Comment: Are you asking about a Draconic Bloodline sorcerer Dragonborn, where the bloodline is Blue and the Dragonborn himself is Red-descended? This is certainly possible, but it doesn't grant both types of breath weapon. By RAW, you only get one type of breath weapon as a Dragonborn, and class features do not give you a new one.